# Erro de carregamento HTTP ao fazer upload na ficha do produto

Tags: magento

Na ficha do produto, em imagens, ao fazer o upload de imagem o seguinte erro é retornado:

> Erro de carregamento HTTP

Já dei permissões ***775*** na pasta ***media*** via FTP.
Já dei permissões ***775*** na pasta ***downloader*** via FTP.

Como posso resolver o problema?

Comment: **Vote hoje! Vote amanhã! Vote sempre! vote consciente!** O seu voto é muito importante para nossa comunidade, contribua conosco e ajude a tornar a Stack Overflow em Português(SOpt) cada vez maior. Você pode saber mais em: [**Vote cedo, vote frequentemente**](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/159/vote-cedo-vote-frequentemente)

Answer (score 1):

Esse erro geralmente é causado devido a proteção do apache no htaccess / .htpasswd. Você precisa desativar a proteção do .htpasswd simplesmente comentando as linhas com #. Após o upload (geralmente de imagem no produto) basta descomentar liberando e apagando as hasttags # , hospedando novamente no servidor , reiniciando o serviço e pronto. problema resolvido

---

Referência: http://www.missionbaymedia.com/blog/7/magento-image-upload-gives-22upload-http-error-22.php/7/magento-image-upload-gives-22upload-http-error-22